# Creating .html file from logfile

Tags: html, bash, grep, cat

I need a script which converts log files into easily viewable .html files, accessible by "anyone".

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

## The purpose of this script is to create .html files from log files, with the ability to optionally GREP for certain strings

if [ "$2" == "" ];
then
        echo "Usage : $0 [Source Log file] [Output HTML file] [String to grep (if applicable)]"
        exit 255
fi;

LOGFILE=$1
OUTPUTFILE=$2
GREPSTRING=$3

if [ "$3" == "" ];
then
        echo "Cat'ing $LOGFILE to $OUTPUTFILE"
        LOGCONTENTS=`cat $LOGFILE`

else
        echo "Grep'ing for $GREPSTRING in $LOGFILE"
        LOGCONTENTS=`grep --color $GREPSTRING $LOGFILE | sed -e "s/^.*$/&1\n/"`
fi;

# Below is the html heading which will be appended to the final .html file
HEADING="<html><body><h1>Log output for: $LOGFILE</h1>"

# Below is the end of the html file
END="</body></html>"

# Below all the prepared variables are stitched together to the OUTPUT/LOG FILE
echo $HEADING > $OUTPUTFILE
echo $LOGCONTENTS >> $OUTPUTFILE
echo $END >> $OUTPUTFILE


# For debugging, enable the lines below
echo $LOGCONTENTS
echo "Done preparing $OUTPUTFILE"
```

My problem is that the output, no matter how much I play with CAT, GREP, SED etc, does not preserve line breaks. It is essential for the output file to look more or less like when doing a normal tail -f or cat.

Comment: Just wrap it all in `<pre>` tags, or your local preferred CSS implementation of same.

Comment: But before anything will work, you need to double-quote the variables you `echo`.

Comment: also change all '==' to '='

Answer (score 4):

Instead of copying things into variables (and then misquoting them), here's a significant refactoring.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec >"$2"
cat <<HERE
<html><body><h1>Log output for: $1</h1>
<pre>
HERE
grep "${3:-^}" "$1"
echo '</pre></body></html>'
```

Because HTML cannot display terminal color codes anyway, I took out the `--color` option. If you have a suitable filter for translating to HTML color tags, by all means throw it in.

Notice also that the regex will default to one which matches all lines if you don't supply a third command-line argument.

Many browsers will render the lone opening `<pre>` tag as an unattractive empty line, but fixing that is hardly essential here. Break it out into a separate `echo -n '<pre>'` if it bothers you.

Comment: And my favorite part is the face: `3:-^}` :)

Comment: The nice thing about using `pre` here is that one can easily add a class tag and fashion the log text as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're going to HTML, you need to replace line break characters (using `sed` or whatever) with `<br/>`, the HTML line break. HTML ignores CR/LF characters normally in free flowing text.

So you could use `sed` as below. I removed the `1`s as their purpose is not explained, but you could put them back in if you require.

```
if [ "$3" == "" ];
then
        echo "Cat'ing $LOGFILE to $OUTPUTFILE"
        LOGCONTENTS=`sed -e "s/^.*$/&<br\/>/" $LOGFILE`

else
        echo "Grep'ing for $GREPSTRING in $LOGFILE"
        LOGCONTENTS=`grep --color $GREPSTRING $LOGFILE | sed -e "s/^.*$/&<br\/>/"`
fi;
```

Comment: I don't think the `sed` script to add a `1` at the end of each line is actually intentional or useful, but that's of course just speculation. Just `sed 's/$/1/'` does that more succinctly if it's really desired.

Comment: @tripleee I was following the lead of what the OP had been using is all, assuming they set it up the way they wanted (short of having the line breaks working). I have clarified that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

public class Log4jHTMLlayout extends HTMLLayout {
    protected final int BUF_SIZE = 256;
    protected final int MAX_CAPACITY = 1024;
    static String TRACE_PREFIX = "
    ";
    private StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer(BUF_SIZE);
    public static final String LOCATION_INFO_OPTION = "LocationInfo";

```
public String format(LoggingEvent event) {

    if (sbuf.capacity() > MAX_CAPACITY) {
        sbuf = new StringBuffer(BUF_SIZE);
    } else {
        sbuf.setLength(0);
    }

    sbuf.append(Layout.LINE_SEP + "<tr>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);

    sbuf.append("<td>");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    //sbuf.append(event.timeStamp - LoggingEvent.getStartTime());
    Timestamp stmp=new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    sbuf.append(stmp.toString());
    sbuf.append("</td>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);

    String escapedThread = Transform.escapeTags(event.getThreadName());
    sbuf.append("<td title=\"" + escapedThread + " thread\">");
    sbuf.append(escapedThread);
    sbuf.append("</td>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);

    sbuf.append("<td title=\"Level\">");
    if (event.getLevel().equals(Level.DEBUG)) {
        sbuf.append("<font color=\"#339933\">");
        sbuf.append(Transform.escapeTags(String.valueOf(event.getLevel())));
        sbuf.append("</font>");
    } else if (event.getLevel().isGreaterOrEqual(Level.WARN)) {
        sbuf.append("<font color=\"#993300\"><strong>");
        sbuf.append(Transform.escapeTags(String.valueOf(event.getLevel())));
        sbuf.append("</strong></font>");
    } else {
        sbuf.append(Transform.escapeTags(String.valueOf(event.getLevel())));
    }
    sbuf.append("</td>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);

    String escapedLogger = Transform.escapeTags(event.getLoggerName());
    sbuf.append("<td title=\"" + escapedLogger + " category\">");
    sbuf.append(escapedLogger);
    sbuf.append("</td>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);

    if (getLocationInfo()) {
        LocationInfo locInfo = event.getLocationInformation();
        sbuf.append("<td>");
        sbuf.append(Transform.escapeTags(locInfo.getFileName()));
        sbuf.append(':');
        sbuf.append(locInfo.getLineNumber());
        sbuf.append("</td>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    }

    sbuf.append("<td title=\"Message\">");
    sbuf.append(Transform.escapeTags(event.getRenderedMessage()));
    sbuf.append("</td>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("</tr>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);

    if (event.getNDC() != null) {
        sbuf.append("<tr><td bgcolor=\"#EEEEEE\" style=\"font-size : xx-small;\" colspan=\"6\" title=\"Nested Diagnostic Context\">");
        sbuf.append("NDC: " + Transform.escapeTags(event.getNDC()));
        sbuf.append("</td></tr>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    }

    String[] s = event.getThrowableStrRep();
    if (s != null) {
        sbuf.append("<tr><td bgcolor=\"#993300\" style=\"color:White; font-size : xx-small;\" colspan=\"6\">");
        appendThrowableAsHTML(s, sbuf,true);
        sbuf.append("</td></tr>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    }

    return sbuf.toString();

}

public void appendThrowableAsHTML(String[] s, StringBuffer sbuf,boolean isAppend) {
         if(s != null) {
           int len = s.length;
           if(len == 0)
               return;
           sbuf.append(Transform.escapeTags(s[0]));
           sbuf.append(Layout.LINE_SEP);
           for(int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                sbuf.append(TRACE_PREFIX);
                sbuf.append(Transform.escapeTags(s[i]));
                sbuf.append(Layout.LINE_SEP);
           }
       }
}
public String getHeader() {
    StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
    sbuf.append("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<html>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<head>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<title>" + getTitle() + "</title>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<style type=\"text/css\">" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<!--" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("body, table {font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: x-small;}" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("th {background: #336699; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left;}" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("-->" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("</style>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("</head>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<body bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" topmargin=\"6\" leftmargin=\"6\">" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<hr size=\"1\" noshade>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("Log session start time " + new java.util.Date() + "<br>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<br>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"4\" border=\"1\" bordercolor=\"#224466\" width=\"100%\">" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<tr>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<th>Time</th>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<th>Thread</th>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<th>Level</th>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("<th>Category</th>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    if (getLocationInfo()) {
        sbuf.append("<th>File:Line</th>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    }
    sbuf.append("<th>Message</th>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    sbuf.append("</tr>" + Layout.LINE_SEP);
    return sbuf.toString();
}
```

}
**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ccat](https://github.com/jingweno/ccat) for this purpose.

If you are on Ubuntu follow [install](https://launchpad.net/~twodopeshaggy/+archive/ubuntu/ccat) it first and convert a log file to html file as shown below.

```
ccat check_valgrind_log.log --html > check_valgrind_log.html
```

I used this package to convert valgrind log to an html file, which gives a nice coloured output.